# TransactionScope are database updates available on reads within the same transaction

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g

I have a situation where I am using a transaction scope in .NET.

Within it are multiple method calls, the first perform database updates, and then the last reads the database.

My question is will the database reads pick up the changes in the first method calls that update the databases (note there are commits in these methods, but they are not truly committed until the transaction scope completes).

E.g Using TransactionScope.

{

Method 1 (Insert new comment into database).

Method 2 (Retrieve all comments from database).

complete.

}

Will method 2 results include the method 1 insert?

Thing that is confusing me is that I have ran loads of tests, and sometimes the update is there, sometimes its not!?!

I am aware there are isolation levels (at a high level), is there one that would allow reads to uncommitted data ONLY within the transactionscope?

Any and all help greatly appreciated......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the purpose of transactions. Think about the situation where you have 2 tables, and 1 foreign keys the other. In your transaction, you insert into one and then the other one with a foreign key of your first insert, and it works. If the data was not available to you, the transaction would be pointless: it would be one operation at a time, which would be atomic, and thus negate the need for transactions.

Comment: Yes I see your point and agree, I think the data inserted in the first should be available for later steps in the same transaction. I guess my confusion is why in some of my tests the first insert isn't always appearing on a read later in the transaction....

Comment: I would have to suspect bad logic in your program. If you inserted successfully in the transaction, a follow-up read of the data prior to commit or abort should always return the data.

Comment: user2026086 i think it can be becouse of transaction loss or always using other connection that dispose changes in you current transaction. Its very imporatnt to user Transaction.Connection in all operations that need connections to db like execute command. And make siure you have always assing sqlcommand.Transaction = yourTransaction. I speculate witout code but i am siure that u can recieve inserted value in begining of trans and recieve it at the end until u wont rollback :) and remember dispose = rollback // no commit = rollback // nothing happen - mssql auto rollback

Comment: Thanks again for the responses. I just wanted to make sure my understanding of transactionscope was correct, and it sounds like it is - that within it any changes to the database should be available for other reads within the scope and once commited will then be available for users outside the transaction. I guess there may be something wrong with my code/set up which is causing the inconsistent results......

Answer (score 1):

You can do any operations on databases that you want (ms-sql), and until you don't make

> transaction.commit()

any changes will appear.

Even if you insert NEW record in one transaction you can get its value in this same transaction. (ofc if you wont rollback()) it.